# What is iTunes for Windows written of?

Tags: windows, cocoa, itunes

I was wondering it for a long time since Apple released iTunes for Windows. What did they use to write iTunes for Windows? It seems completely with its own UI components and everything is contained inside it. It even uses QuickTime resources files. Can we assume that they've Cocoa working with windows. Anyway, my main question is, is there any known (public or private) tool/language/framework used in developing iTunes for Windows?

Comment: No Cocoa for Windows.  Heck, I wish the Mac version of iTunes was Cocoa.  It's still using Carbon.  Took them long enough to port the Finder from Carbon too, in my opinion :)

Comment: Also, you might try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm fairly certain the Windows port of iTunes was forged from black magic in the firey pits of Hell itself...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it cannot be answered without internal Apple knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but if the reason you're asking is that you want to port a cocoa application to Windows, you might be interested in this:

http://code.google.com/p/cocotron/

bit more info here:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/04/design-of-multi-platform-app-using.html
http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/04/porting-mac-program-to-windows-using.html

Haven't used it myself, but I gather they've got enough done to make a useable cross-platform Cocoa app.

Answer (score 2):

itunes for both mac and windows are written in c++ as it is easier to port between operating systems with much or the same codebase

Comment: http://forum.soft32.com/mac/language-write-Win32-iTunes-ftopict49576.html  as well the windows version is Win32 and uses COM most applications of this type are written in c/c++ or vb iTunes also predates osx so it is unlikely (unless they have rewritten alot of the codebase for the mac version only) that it uses objective-c as it is a mac only language

Comment: no official reference just my own research from writing scripts against the itunes api dlls